# The influxdb and chronograph showing no result

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I am maintaining a MVP web based app  in windows.
The previous developer has been using the influxdb and chronograph to record most used controllers in 10 minutes, 1 hour, and 1 day interval.
Following his documentation, these are steps I did :

1. Go to production, get the data.
2. Go to local computer, restore data and analyse it.

I could get the data and restore data, but somehow it is showing 'no result' in the chronograph query.
Has anybody encountered this before?
Any wisdoms are much appreciated, thanks